# Sharepoint online navigation caching?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am using Aplication Customizer to add jQuery and custom javascript to my page:

```
 let current_date: Date = new Date();
let date_String: string = current_date.toString();
date_String = current_date.toISOString()
console.log('date_string = %s', date_String);
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://8lbg15.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/SiteAssets/caj23.css?d=' + date_String);
//SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://8lbg15.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/SiteAssets/jquery-3.6.3.min.js?d=' + date_String)
//SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://8lbg15.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/SiteAssets/caj23.js?d=' + date_String);

SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://8lbg15.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/SiteAssets/jquery-3.6.3.min.js?d=' + date_String, {
  globalExportsName: 'jQuery'
}).then(($: any) => {
  $(function () {
    console.log('jQuery is loaded');
  });
  SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://8lbg15.sharepoint.com/sites/KnowledgeBase/SiteAssets/caj23.js?d=' + date_String, {}).then(() => {
    //...do something
  });
});
```

The code runs fine when I open the page. However, if I navigate to the page from the main site navigation (ie the mega menu) the code doesn't run. Yet if I click on the link a second time in the nav, it loads the page and the code runs.

In other words, it doesn't rung when you change pages via the nav, but if you load the same page (or reload the page with F5) it does!!!

Is this some kind of  caching issue? I am using Sharepoint Modern/Online so there is no caching setting for the site.

Any solutions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, as far as I know, custom code is usually loaded when the entire page is refreshed. And the first time you enter the page via the navigation, the entire page refresh is not triggered, so no code does not take effect.

SharePoint Online works online. If you are worried that the cache has affected this matter, you can try to clear the cache of the browser, or switch to the private mode to see if the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a routing interceptor that will check your link and if appropriate, do a partial navigation, ie avoiding a full page load.

To work around and force javascript to run, add
data-interception="off"
to all links eg by script

$('a').attr("data-interception", "off");